# Showing image in Swift Playground Markup

Tags: xcode, swift-playground

I'd like to show image in my markup document in swift playground file. Here is the code:

```
//: ![Alt text](1.png) 
//: ![Xcode icon](http://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/assets/elements/icons/128x128/xcode.png "Some hover text")
```

1.png is in the same directory as my playground file. But both are not working.

[image]

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that your image in the Playground Resource folder and then select the Show Rendered Markup from the Xcode editing menu.

Comment: It's my pleasure :)